# Does moving a file in Subversion to a less restricted folder expose its version and log history?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repo set up like this, where lots of people can access *^/public* but only a few can access *^/restricted_zone*:

```
^/restricted_zone/calculate_sales.py
^/public/scripts/
```

Revision `1000` of `calculate_sales.py` has hardcoded sensitive information in it I need to keep private, but revision `1005` is sanitized and should be available to everyone. I'd like to move `calculate_sales.py` down to *^/public/scripts*, but I'm worried that this will expose the full log history including the sensitive revision `1000`.

I could move the file without Subversion's knowledge and start a new history, but I'd like to preserve the unbroken history for people who *do* have visibility of *^/restricted_zone* if possible. Given these circumstances:

1) Is it safe to move the current `calculate_sales.py` down to public if revision `1000` contained sensitive information?

2) Is it safe to move the current `calculate_sales.py` down to public if revision `1000`'s commit message contained sensitive information?

Comment: For further clarity: I sit halfway up a fairly rigid bureaucracy and don't have personal access to anybody with a "public-permissions-only" account, so unfortunately I can't trial & error this to find out the behaviour. I imagine the steps would be (1) create `mydoc.txt` in the private zone containing text "secret words here" (2) update `mydoc.txt` to contain text "public words now", (3) move `mydoc.txt` down to public zone, (4) ask a colleague with public-permissions-only whether they can inspect the revision history and read the sentence "secret words here" in an old revision.

Comment: You don't have to use comments when adding new info. SO is not a forum you can simply edit your question and add the new info there.